# for statement with decimal numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, double

I know how to increment by 1 with for loops, like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

would print out 0 to 8, but I don't know how to make a for loop that would increment by a decimal number, like 0.1. In my case, I am trying to right a for loop that would increment by 0.1 starting from -1.00 to 1.00. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @nhgrif - this question may be a duplicate, but it is MUCH better than the other as it is clearer and more concise.

Answer (score 4):

First we consider the obvious approach:

```
for(double i = -1; i <= 1; i += 0.1){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

There are floating point issues, *especially* since you use 0.1 as the increment. If you run the code, this is the output:

```
-1.0
-0.9
-0.8
-0.7000000000000001
-0.6000000000000001
-0.5000000000000001
-0.40000000000000013
-0.30000000000000016
-0.20000000000000015
-0.10000000000000014
-1.3877787807814457E-16
0.09999999999999987
0.19999999999999987
0.2999999999999999
0.3999999999999999
0.4999999999999999
0.5999999999999999
0.6999999999999998
0.7999999999999998
0.8999999999999998
0.9999999999999998
```

Using a mapping of `int` to `double` yields better results:

```
for(int i = -10; i <= 10; i++){
    System.out.println(i / 10.0);
}
```

Output:

```
-1.0
-0.9
-0.8
-0.7
-0.6
-0.5
-0.4
-0.3
-0.2
-0.1
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:-

```
for(double i = 0; i < 10.0; i += 0.1)
```

or may be like this as you should avoid double in for loops:

```
for (int n = 0; n <= 9; n++) {
    double i = 0.1 * n;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 I don't see any reason to downvote this answer

Answer (score 0):

To prevent floating point arithmetic errors, use an int until you need to display it:

```
    for (int i = -10; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println((double)i/10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to iterate through -1.0 to 1.0

```
for(int i=-100; i<=100; i+=10) {
    double x = i/100.0;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

This outputs:

```
-1.0
-0.9
-0.8
-0.7
-0.6
-0.5
-0.4
-0.3
-0.2
-0.1
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```